# Change bone axis orientation

Tags: bones, transforms

I was wondering if anyone knows an answer to this simple question. Googling did not give me satisfactory solutions. I have never dealt with bones previously, and they seem to be rather complicated.

**The question is as follows:**

Consider the following bone axis orientation (pose mode selected):

[image]

The Y-axis is oriented along the bone length. What I need for the script is to make the X-axis orient along the bone length. Basically, I need to rotate the whole axis system 90 degrees around Z-axis.

I would really love to have this orientation for the script. Converting the script itself would be highly problematic.

**To conclude with:** Can I rotate the pivot 90 degrees around the Z-axis?

I would very much appreciate if anyone replies to this.

Cheers!

Comment: This question is very interesting and it will be awsome if there is someone that can answer you. I can tell you, for my experience, that the Y-axis follow always the lenght of its bone . . . however i hope to be wrong ^^

Comment: have you tried using custom orientations or gimbal? If not, I can add a custom answer for clarity

Comment: So I tried using custom orientation, however at this point I don't know how to write a script to make the object rotate around custom axis. The scripting examples I saw either explain how rotate the object around the local axis, or global one by directly applying matrix transformation.

Comment: I feel you may be overcomplicating it. Blender already has options available, no need to write a script.

Comment: Well, I need scripting simply because I have real-life information from sensors I need to feed into my model. I already did that for a simple robot arm. Now I need a bit more complicated model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicate one of your bones and rotate 90 degrees on the Z axis. This will be the object from which we will make the desired set of axes.

[image: 1]

Open the properties panel using <kbd>N</kbd> and press <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>spacebar</kbd> to create a custom axis. In the properties panel under "Transform Orientation" you can rename your custom axis, here I've named it "x = y and y = x".

[image: 2]

Now select your original bones, X and Y have traded axes. In the 3D window footer, you can see we are now using the custom orientation created.

[image: 3]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Out of date for Blender 3.2 - any other solutions?