# How can I rotate or chance the axis orientation of each bone individually?

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify, axis

[image]I'm new to blender so please be patient and detailed with your anwsers even this may be a stupid question.
So my current situation is that I build a basic rig with rigify in Blender that I want to use in Unreal Engine.
All bones in Blender have an orientation, that should be: Y-Axis pointing down, Z-Axis pointing backwards and the X-Axis point to the right.
But not every bone in my skeleton or rig has this orientation.
The foot and toe bone have a different, kind of weird, orientation, so I thought I could fix this manully, but I can't find any good solution to this.
When I select the bone in "Edit or Pose-Mode" and press "R" for rotate or select the rotation-tool, it will pop up and I can screw on it but nothing will happen.
Maybe the screenshot will give you an better example what I want to  achieve

Answer (score 0):

Select the bone in Edit mode. Click the green bone icon in the R/H Properties panel and change the Roll setting under Transform.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if that is what you really want. See if this answer is any more helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52822/change-bone-axis-orientation There's also [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NWTMXCwFwQ) tutorial which may help although I haven't watched it.

Comment: hey, thanks for your respond. Its not exactly what I was looking for because this only changes the rotation of the bone on it's self axis, but I want to change the axis-orientation that they are pointing in a different direction. When you look at my screenshot above the bone "roll" only rotate on the Z Axis but i want that on the lower sphere the Z-Axis is pointing straight backwards, the Y-Axis must look straight down and the X-Axis must facing straight downwards. That can't be fixed with bone roll and it can't be fixed with local rotation, when i roate them nothing happens

Comment: Yes. I realised that after posting my answer. That's why I added the further comment underneath!

Comment: yes, thanks for that but this isn't an export problem. I will have a look at the forum post! maybe this will help!

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure whether what you're asking is actually possible in Blender. Perhaps you should add to your question **why** you want the axis to point in the direction you want and maybe one of the animation experts in here will be able to help. I also realise that the YT link I posted was for importing to Blender, not exporting to Unreal. There's another longer YT video [here](https://youtu.be/jzUyS9ZP9Qg) on exporting which might be worth watching.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so hard to do en masse, provided you don't need to preserve bone lengths; and there's no reason you'd need to preserve bone lengths, because anything that would get broken by changes in bone length is going to be broken by these changes anyways.  (In particular, **rigify** is going to get broken.  You have that as a tag, but you haven't specified that you want to do this on a rigify rig.)

First, make sure that you have no bones that are "connected", which is an official Blender property for bones set when bones are parented.  You can see if a bone is connected on properties/bone/relations/connected in Edit mode. Select all and alt-p-> disconnect bone to remove that property from all bones.

Once we do that, it's relatively easy to get the orientation you want.  Set pivot point to individual origins, orientation to global, then s shift z to scale the tail of all bones to the same XY location as their heads.

This leaves some bones' Y axes pointing upwards rather than downwards; not sure if that's a problem for you.  These bones can all be selected and then scaled by -1.

Finally, to set the X + Z axis, enter a rear orthogonal view (should be ctrl numpad 1), then use a recalculate roll operation, using the "view axis" for the roll recalculation.

This will break nearly any rig that is using constraints or animation built for different local axes-- but there's nothing specific about this technique regarding that, that will be true for this entire question.  Just feel like I have to emphasize that in case anyone was unaware.